# Cannot print array elements in listbox using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to print array elements in console and in listbox (using tKinter), when a button is clicked. The elements are being printed on console, but not in the GUI. Below is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

from dbprocessor import DbProcessor

window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome To Pin Finder")

lbl = Label(window, text="Search for PCBa_Cards", font=("Arial Bold", 8))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)
search = Entry(window, width=20)
search.focus()
search.grid(column=0, row=4)

listbox = Listbox(window)

dp = DbProcessor()


def clicked():
    res = "WELCOME " + search.get()
    lbl.configure(text=res)
    records = dp.connectandread(search.get())
    for row in records:
        print(str(row))
        listbox.insert(END, str(row))
    # lbl.configure(text=str(records))
    #listbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)


lbl.grid(column=1, row=5)
btn = Button(window, text="Search", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row=4)

window.mainloop()
```

I can see the array elements in the console, but not in the listbox. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add the listbox to the display. You need to call the `grid` method of `listbox`.